# Binding functions in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I am binding function in two ways, the first one is working fine, but its a bad approach to use es6 function syntax inside return method as it calls a new method on every instance, all the code is working fine, i just need help with binding function. Binding in return statement works fine.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './ColorBox.css';

export default class ColorBox extends Component{
    //Constructor
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { copied: false};
    }
    
    // Not binded because its called inside the binded function, althrough it doesnot matter
    changeCopyState(){ 
        this.setState({ copied: true}, () => (
            setTimeout(() => (
                this.setState({copied: false})
            ), 1500)
        ))
    }

    // Function to copy color code to clipboard
    copyToClipBoard(str) {
        const element = document.createElement('textarea');
        element.value = str;
        document.body.appendChild(element);//insert textarea into html body
        element.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');//internal command to copy from text area
        document.body.removeChild(element);//remove after coping command
        this.changeCopyState();
    }

    render(){
        let {name, background} = this.props;
        let {copied} = this.state;  
        return (
            <div style={{ background}} className="ColorBox">
                <div style={{ background }} className={`copy-overlay ${ copied && "show"}`} /> 
                    <div className="box-content">
                        <span>{name}</span>
                    </div>
                    <button className="copy-button" onClick={() => this.copyToClipBoard(background)}>Copy</button>
                <span className="more-shades">More</span>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

now if i try to bind the function inside the constructor, it will give me an error of exceeding limit on calling function etc, why is this behaviour occurring.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './ColorBox.css';

export default class ColorBox extends Component{
    //Constructor
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { copied: false};
        this.copyToClipBoard = this.copyToClipBoard.bind(this);
    }
    
    // Not binded because its called inside the binded function, althrough it doesnot matter
    changeCopyState(){ 
        this.setState({ copied: true}, () => (
            setTimeout(() => (
                this.setState({copied: false})
            ), 1500)
        ))
    }

    // Function to copy color code to clipboard
    copyToClipBoard(str) {
        const element = document.createElement('textarea');
        element.value = str;
        document.body.appendChild(element);//insert textarea into html body
        element.select();
        document.execCommand('copy');//internal command to copy from text area
        document.body.removeChild(element);//remove after coping command
        this.changeCopyState();
    }

    render(){
        let {name, background} = this.props;
        let {copied} = this.state;  
        return (
            <div style={{ background}} className="ColorBox">
                <div style={{ background }} className={`copy-overlay ${ copied && "show"}`} /> 
                    <div className="box-content">
                        <span>{name}</span>
                    </div>
                    <button className="copy-button" onClick={this.copyToClipBoard(background)}>Copy</button>
                <span className="more-shades">More</span>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Well because you're directly calling it in the JSX, so when the component renders, it calls that function. But why are you passing `this.props.background` to `copyToClipBoard` anyway? You already have access to it inside that function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

`onClick={this.copyToClipBoard(background)}` invokes the callback immediately, thus causing the render looping you see.

## Solutions

1. Convert `copyToClipBoard` to a curried function so it consumes a `background` argument, closed over in scope, and returns a function to be used as the callback.

   ```
   // Function to copy color code to clipboard
   copyToClipBoard(str) {
     return () => {
       const element = document.createElement('textarea');
       element.value = str;
       document.body.appendChild(element); //insert textarea into html body
       element.select();
       document.execCommand('copy'); //internal command to copy from text area
       document.body.removeChild(element); //remove after coping command
       this.changeCopyState();
     };
   }
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   <button
     className="copy-button"
     onClick={this.copyToClipBoard(background)} // <-- returns callback handler
   >
     Copy
   </button>
   ```
2. Convert `copyToClipBoard` to a curried arrow function so `this` is bound automatically and you don't need the binding in the `constructor`.

   ```
   // Function to copy color code to clipboard
   copyToClipBoard = (str) => () => {
     const element = document.createElement('textarea');
     element.value = str;
     document.body.appendChild(element); //insert textarea into html body
     element.select();
     document.execCommand('copy'); //internal command to copy from text area
     document.body.removeChild(element); //remove after coping command
     this.changeCopyState();
   };
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   <button
     className="copy-button"
     onClick={this.copyToClipBoard(background)} // <-- returns callback handler
   >
     Copy
   </button>
   ```
3. `background` is available already in `props`, just consume it from there.

   ```
   // Function to copy color code to clipboard
   copyToClipBoard(str) {
     const { background } = this.props; // <-- destructure from props

     const element = document.createElement('textarea');
     element.value = background; // <-- use background
     document.body.appendChild(element); //insert textarea into html body
     element.select();
     document.execCommand('copy'); //internal command to copy from text area
     document.body.removeChild(element); //remove after coping command
     this.changeCopyState();
   }
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   <button
     className="copy-button"
     onClick={this.copyToClipBoard} // <-- just attach handler
   >
     Copy
   </button>
   ```

Comment: solution 3rd is the most simpler, I have to go with it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of a circular reference. You're accessing something which is accessing something, resulting in an infinite amount of calls and causing the call stack to exceed its limit.

You could instead just do the binding inside of the onClick method:

```
<button className="copy-button" onClick={this.copyToClipBoard.bind(this, background)}>Copy</button>
```